# Possible to use PicoContainer (Dependency injection) without constructor parameters?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cucumber, cucumber-java, picocontainer

I need to achieve dependency injection using PicoContainer without passing constructor parameters, current setup:

```
public class Shared_Data  {

    public Account_Pojo account_pojo;

    public Shared_Data(Account_Pojo account_pojo) {
        this.account_pojo = account_pojo;
    }
```

In the above example I need to achieve DI using PicoContainer without passing: Account_Pojo account_pojo as a parameter to the constructor, is this even possible?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
public class Shared_Data {
    public Account_Pojo account_pojo;

    public Shared_Data() {
    }

    public void setAccount_pojo(Account_Pojo account_pojo) {
        this.account_pojo = account_pojo;
    }

    public Account_Pojo getAccount_pojo() {
        setAccount_pojo(account_pojo);
        return account_pojo;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need this? it's kinda antipattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a pico container  with a `SetterInjection` component factory[0].

```
pico = new DefaultPicoContainer(new SetterInjection());
pico.addComponent(Account_Pojo.class);
```

Something like this should work.

[0] http://picocontainer.com/setter-injection.html

Comment: tried the following with no luck :/
        DefaultPicoContainer pico = new DefaultPicoContainer(new SetterInjection());
        pico.addComponent(Account_Pojo.class);
        Account_Pojo account_pojo = pico.getComponent(Account_Pojo.class);
        account_pojo.setFirstName("test123");

Comment: What is no luck exactly? Compile errors, stack traces?

Comment: Seems Im seeing the following exception: org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: sharedStepsUtils.account.Account_Pojo has unsatisfied dependencies [class java.lang.String] for members [public void sharedStepsUtils.account.Account_Pojo.setEmailAddress(java.lang.String)..

Comment: @Gbru Side-effect of using `SetterInjection` component factory is that all methods starting with `set` will be used to create the component. `SetterInjection` accepts a constructor argument to change this prefix, so you can call your component-configuration methods (for example) `initAccount_pojo` and leave your other setters as-is: `new DefaultPicoContainer(new SetterInjection("init"));`

Comment: thanks @Elias looks like the following works, when added to a sole cucumber step just need to figure out why it doesnt work when calling the get method from a different step: DefaultPicoContainer pico = new DefaultPicoContainer(new SetterInjection("init"));
        pico.addComponent(Account_Pojo.class);
        Account_Pojo account_pojo = pico.getComponent(Account_Pojo.class);
        account_pojo.setFirstName("joe");
        account_pojo.getFirstName();

Comment: @Gbru You did not provide details of your `getFirstName` method. Consider accepting the answer and asking a new one with your new question.